# Capitalization works on blur but not set variables in Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, capitalization

I have a problem using a directive to capitalize input for a field in my form.

I am using a directive I found on SO that does the trick well when the user interacts with the field. The problem I have is that when data comes in, like it is set from the controller, the directive doesn't run. Even if the field is touched and focus leaves!

Here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/ugrurqAVraRqiJQmDZG7?p=preview

DIRECTIVE

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.directive('capitalize', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        var capitalize = function(inputValue) {
          if (inputValue === undefined) inputValue = '';
          var capitalized = inputValue.toUpperCase();
          if (capitalized !== inputValue) {
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(capitalized);
            modelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return capitalized;
        }
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(capitalize);
        capitalize(scope[attrs.ngModel]); // capitalize initial value
      }
    };
  });

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
  $scope.second = "capitalizeme"
});
```

TEMPLATE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <div>
      <label>Input 2</label>
      <input capitalize type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-model="second" />{{second}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can see that if you type in the field and leave, it will capitalize the whole thing. I tried to use setTouched(); to trigger the validation but that isn't working either.

Comment: Why you don't uppercase the data coming from controller?

Comment: @JonathanAnctil In real life, my app is importing data that a client has entered elsewhere. I can't control what they put in for the import, so I am handling it after it comes in. This is just an example.

Comment: Yeah but the data you import will have to pass through your controller, so you can control the output. Maybe I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

My most promising solution so far is to use a filter. Here is the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9VaxGFjHfun9e6uIrtZ?p=preview

In controller,

```
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
      $scope.second = "capitalizeme";

      $scope.$watch('second', function (val) {
                    $scope.second = $filter('uppercase')(val);
                }, true);
    });
```

In template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <div>
      <label>Input 2</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-model="second" />{{second}}
    </div>
  </body>
```